# Cypress - Click checkbox that depends on the value of another checkbox on a table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, cypress

I have a table with 2 columns of checkboxes.

[image: Here is my setup]

I want to click the first checkbox that has the checked value on the right.
Note: All the checkboxes on the left are not disabled and all the checkboxes on the right are disabled.

Edit:
My DOM looks like this:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {items.map(item) => (
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked={item.posted} disabled />
          </td>
        </tr>
      )
    }
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It is reiterated by the data from the api thats why the checked state of the checkbox is dynamic

Comment: Can you share your HTML DOM ?

Comment: @AlapanDas Update my question

Comment: Does the number of rows change depending on the API call result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding the first checked, then the move to the first checkbox

```js
cy.get('input:checked')       // all checked inputs
  .eq(0)                      // first one
  .parent('td')               // move to cell
  .prev()                     // previous cell
  .find('input')              // it's input 
  .click()
```

---

To clarify how to correctly use `.each()`, you need to use the 3rd parameter `collection` and also `return false` to avoid checking every row which is checked on the right.

```
cy.get('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .each(($ele, index, collection) => {
    if ($ele.is(':checked')) {
      cy.wrap(collection).eq(index-1).click()
      return false;                       // break early to only click the first
    }
  })
```

Comment: I'm using material ui so I had to use parents('td'). I also tried to use .each and it works well, can you explain why it works, like how does the wrap and eq(index-1) works

Comment: Actually I was clarifying the mistakes, but `.eq()`  is the Cypress indexing method when multiple elements are selected. The `.get()` returns all `input` elements (in the order they appear on the page) and puts them in the `collection` parameter, `.wrap()` just makes `collection` work with `.eq()`. So, the `input` before the first one checked is the one you want to click.

Comment: It can be simpler - just use `collection[index-1].click()`, no need to `wrap().eq()` - I didn't notice that before.

Answer (score 0):

You try something like this, iterate over all the checkboxes, once you find the checkbox that is disabled, you can go to a the previous checkbox using `.eq(index-1)` and then perform the `click()`.

```
cy.get('input[type="checkbox"]').each(($ele, index) => {
    if ($ele.is(":disabled")) {
        cy.wrap($ele).eq(index-1).click()
    }
})
```